# Arguments given for element RollingFile are invalid: field 'filePattern' has invalid value 'null', field 'policy' has invalid value 'null'

Tags: xml, java-8, log4j, log4j2

Log4j `1.2.17` to Log4j `2.20.0` version migration.

#### log4j2.xml - XML config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <!-- RollingFile filePattern="logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/app-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.gz" is also not set here. I do want the log files not be rolled automatically. -->
        <RollingFile name="RollingFile"
                     fileName="logs/app.log">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
<!--      I do not want to specify any Policies. So, Policies are not set here      -->
<!--            <Policies>-->
<!--                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB"/>-->
<!--            </Policies>-->
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="trace">
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

#### RollingFile ‘filePattern’ attribute

As far as I know, the RollingFile ‘filePattern’ attribute is optional. If you do not specify the filePattern attribute, then the log files will not be rolled automatically and will not be deleted. The RollingFile appender has an optional filePattern attribute that allows you to specify the name pattern for the log files. This name pattern can be used to roll the log files based on size, date, or other criteria. Without specifying a filePattern, the log files will remain in the same name and will not be rolled.

#### RollingFile the Policies element.

As far as I know, the Policies element is optional. If you do not specify the Policies element, then the log files will not be rolled automatically and will not be deleted.
If you do not specify the Policies element, then the log files will not be rolled automatically and will not be deleted.

However, I find the following exception. How to fix it?

```
org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationException: Arguments given for element RollingFile are invalid: field 'filePattern' has invalid value 'null', field 'policy' has invalid value 'null'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I resolved this issue.

I referred to the following tutorial and customized the example XML config.

#### 3.2. Rolling Over Everyday section.

https://howtodoinjava.com/log4j2/log4j2-rollingfileappender-example/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RollingFile
  name="rollingFile"
  fileName="${LOG_DIR}/application.log"
     filePattern="${LOG_DIR}/application.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.gz"
  ignoreExceptions="false">
  <PatternLayout>
      <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %m%n</Pattern>
  </PatternLayout>
  <Policies>
      <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1"/>
  </Policies>

</RollingFile>
```

I had to specify the filePattern attribute and the TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy.